# Get {{.Host}} inside a range loop - Caddy server browse template

Tags: go, go-templates, caddy

So I can use `{{.Host}}` just fine in the template file, but once inside a `{{range .Items}}` loop it doesn't work since it's trying to get the `.Host` from the `.Items` (array?)thing..

I get this as an error

```
template: listing:41:46: executing "listing" at <.Host>: can't evaluate field Host in type browse.FileInfo
```

I've never used Go before, I've tried reading the [text template documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) page but it's all rather confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{range}} changes the pipeline (the dot, .) to the current Items. You can use {{$.Host}} which will refer to the "top-level" Host.

```
{{$.Host}}
```

golang [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

Answer (score 2):

ooooh, nevermind guys, I knew it was a simple fix.

```
 {{$.Host}}
```

Just add the `$`, then you'll be using the global context again, instead of the context inside of the range loop.

[Source](https://gohugo.io/templates/go-templates/), thanks HUGO for the clear documentation.